# WSUS connection error

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus, windows-update

Server 2008 R2

WSUS 3.2.7600.226

Every min or so, sometimes less, sometimes more I get a connection error and have to reset server node.

```
The WSUS administration console was unable to connect to the WSUS Server via the remote API. 

Verify that the Update Services service, IIS and SQL are running on the server. If the problem     persists, try restarting IIS, SQL, and the Update Services Service.

System.Net.WebException 

-- The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Source
Microsoft.UpdateServices.BaseApi

Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.ClassFactory.CallStaticMethod(Type type, String methodName, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.Subscription.GetSynchronizationHistory(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.Subscription.GetLastSynchronizationInfo()
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.AdminApiAccess.SynchronizationManager.GetLastSynchInfo()
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Pages.ServerSummaryPage.backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)


The WSUS administration console has encountered an unexpected error. This may be a transient error; try restarting the administration console. If this error persists, 

Try removing the persisted preferences for the console by deleting the wsus file under %appdata%\Microsoft\MMC\.


System.NullReferenceException -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source
Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn

Stack Trace:
   at    Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Pages.ServerSummaryPage.backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
```

The application pool is 2.0

Comment: Checked the application pool, iisreset, made sure www service wans't set to interact with the desktop, cleared  %appdata%\Microsoft\MMC\

Comment: Is this the local console or are you accessing it remotely? If local, check to ensure you have enough resources on the server. It's rather hungry for RAM (especially SQL).

Comment: Local. 32gb ram only 16gb in use and 4 cores

Comment: Have you tried a different machine?  This is just a wild guess--hence the comment rather than answer--but I suspect corruption either in MMC itself, or in the SUSDB database.